# What is the default timeout duration for jenkins on doing a git j ob?

Tags: git, jenkins

What is the default timeout duration for jenkins on a git project? I want to know the duration when I am not using jenkins timeout plugin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My project return error timeout after 10min](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038639/my-project-return-error-timeout-after-10min)

Answer (score 0):

Its default time is 10 minutes. To increase duration in the project config page click on add and select 'advanced clone behavior' from dropdown list and add time in minutes.