# My project return error timeout after 10min

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to build git repo project through jenkins. But every time the jenkins return error log as 'my project return error after 10min'. Is there a way to solve this or increase the timeout duration?
My project have a size around 5GB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins time-out while fetching from Github in 10 mins.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954727/jenkins-time-out-while-fetching-from-github-in-10-mins)

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19993460/1030960):

> Workaround #2 - increase the timeout to allow for the long initial
>   clone process to complete, using the `Git.timeOut` property:
>
> ```
> java -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.Git.timeOut=60 -jar jenkins.war
> ```
>
> [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519/how-to-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-its-started-as-a-service-under-windows) is a good example of how to set properties for
>   the Jenkins service.  Also, note that this value is in minutes and not
>   seconds.  This workaround is courtesy of [David](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20387?focusedCommentId=190411&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-190411).

Answer (score 0):

Its default time is 10 minutes. To increase duration in the project config page click on add and select 'advanced clone behavior'. From the dropdown list and add time in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If Repo size is huge and git default timeout is set to 10 minutes.

Increase the timeout with a option "Advanced clone behaviours", in timeout section give 45 minutes to 90 minutes, based on your repo size and bandwidth available.

It will work.